# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bandCount'

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, scp

I have a problem with a plugin (SCP). When I run a raster file (or tried), I get this error. I have read other similar problems, but honestly I am new to this whole programming issue and there are things I don't understand. Could someone explain to me how to solve this?

```
WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/home/kroister/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin-master/maininterface/bandsetTab.py", line 377, in rasterLayerName
              cfg.bst.rasterToBandName(imgNm)
              File "/home/kroister/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin-master/maininterface/bandsetTab.py", line 1027, in rasterToBandName
              b = r.bandCount()
             AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bandCount'
```

Comment: Do you have a temporary raster as input? Try saving it to disk then run the tool

Comment: no, no is a temporary raster =(.